# How to make a beamer slide as shown in the figure?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I was wondering how this kind of slide is made in the beamer.
I wonder how the background is set. Also how the heading is set?

[image: sli]

Any thoughts? It seems like we can use any image we want to set in the background perhaps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently your question is a bit broad, and it leaves all the effort to people that may want to answer the question. Could you provide a small minimal example document, i.e., a beamer presentation with one slide on it that shows the slide title and the equations, but without the background? That makes it easier for potential answerers to get started on the real issue (the background) without spending time in preparations.

Comment: That said, a background with clouds is maybe not the most professional choice (unless you have a special reason for it), you could consider using one of the predefined Beamer styles to present your content.

Comment: Please clarify the issue, or issues, you’re struggling with the most? The cloud background, the red lettering of the title, the alignment of the equations, all of the above, or something else entirely? BTW, I share @Marijn’s opinion about the non-advisability of the cloud background. Your presentation isn’t about selling a vacation package to consumers, is it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments,  I was thinking about the background, how we can insert an image of choice in the background in a beamer theme? Seems not so professional though

Comment: see [How to let background image cover entire Beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136164/how-to-let-background-image-cover-entire-beamer-slide?rq=1)